# C++ loop that run until i enter correct values

Tags: c++, loops, do-while, binomial-coefficients

This is a program which calculates the binomial coefficient. No when i enter for k value that is > n the program crashеs.But I wonder how i can do so when I enter k> n the  program to bring me back to enter new values that are correct(n>k). The program stops when I enter correct values (n>k).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
  // Base Cases
  if (k==0 || k==n)
    return 1;
 else
  return  binomialCoeff(n-1, k-1) + binomialCoeff(n-1, k);
}
int main()
{
   int n,k;
   cin >>n;
   cin>>k;
    printf("Value of C(%d, %d) is %d ", n, k, binomialCoeff(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe with do while loop?
Something like this:

```
do     {
       cin >>n;
       cin>>k;
       }while(n>k);
```

But this loop is not working.

Comment: You also need to check the state of `std::cin`. If the read failed, say you entered something that isn't a number, you'll get stuck in an infinite loop. Just `while (std::cin && n>k)`

Comment: ‘*Not working*’ is not a good enough description of a problem. *How* does it not work? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it loop forever? Did something catch fire?

Comment: while(1)
 {
  cin >> n;
  cin >> k;
  if(n>k)
   break;
 }

I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int main()
{
    int n, k;

    do {
        printf("Enter n and k values: ");
        cin >> n >> k;
    } while (n < k);

    printf("Value of C(%d, %d) is %d ", n, k, binomialCoeff(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

However, shouldn't `binomialCoeff()` just return `0` if `(n < k)`?

```
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0 || k == n)
        return 1;
    else if (n < k)
        return 0;
    else
        return  binomialCoeff(n - 1, k - 1) + binomialCoeff(n - 1, k);
}
```

If you want to catch inputs that are not integers try the following:

```
#include <limits>
...

int main()
{
    int n, k;

    while (!(cin >> n) || !(cin >> k) || (n < k)) {
        cout << "inavlid input! try again" << endl;
        /* clear failbit */
        cin.clear();
        /* discard invalid input */
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    printf("Value of C(%d, %d) is %d\n", n, k, binomialCoeff(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better because a user can do anything with a program, knowingly or unknowingly. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: @sergej Thank you. Now i see how stupid is my question.I tried the same  thing but the compiler gives me an error an i give up. I just don't understand why in this case you use std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' in cin.ignore();

Comment: @Fingolfin You are welcome. Please see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).